# JQuery Autocomplete Stops Working After Postback

Tags: jquery-ui, sharepoint-2010, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete script that works ok in the sense that it shows the options to select from after the user types 2 letters. Now, the problem I have is that after the selection is made and the text field is filled out, the script stops. For example, if I make a selection from the given entries, and for some reason I have clear the text field, once I start typing again, the autocomplete doesn't show anything at all.

The form performs a postback everytime I select values from a couple of dropdown controls, and I noticed the script stops once the postbacks are triggered. Is there any way I can 
have the scripts running after each postback?

If anybody can point the right directions, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

```
<script language="javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

//Wait ##### seconds for form to load before calling the function.
window.onload = function(){
    window.setTimeout(readyCall, 1000);
}

function readyCall(){

//Variable for Array where Title column values will be pushed to.
var Requestors = [];

//Variable for the Requestor Text Field.
var RequestorField = "input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T2']"

//Call the SPServices library.
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    listName: "Requestor",
    CAMLViewFields: "",
    async: false,
    completefunc: function (xData, Status){
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
            Requestors.push($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
        }); 
    } 
}); 

//Input field from form.
$(RequestorField).autocomplete({
    source: Requestors,
    minLength: 3,
    focus: function(event, ui){
        $(RequestorField).val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
        }       
    }); 
} 
</script>
```